# Function for javascript doesn't rerun when different button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the `<h4>` tag to update if a different button is pressed, but it doesn't change. I want the two functions to rerun every time I click a button.

```js
function submit(clicked_id) {
  var answer = document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML;
  answercheck()
}

function answercheck() {
  if (answer != "George Washington") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You are incorrect.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<h3>Who is the first president of the United States?</h3>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans1">Benjamin Franklin</button>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans2">George Washington</button>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans3">Thomas Edison</button>
<h4 id="answer"></h4>
```

Comment: `var` variables are function scoped.  `answer` created in `submit` does not exist in `answercheck`

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `answer` is wrong. It's bound to your submit function. Declare it outside of it so both functions can access it:

```js
var answer;
function submit(clicked_id) {
  answer = document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML;
  answercheck()
}

function answercheck() {
  if (answer != "George Washington") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You are incorrect.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<h3>Who is the first president of the United States?</h3>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans1">Benjamin Franklin</button>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans2">George Washington</button>
<button onclick="submit(this.id);" id="ans3">Thomas Edison</button>
<h4 id="answer"></h4>
```